# Jquery form validate not showing messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

can anyone tell me why this code is not showing the custom jquery messages, everything else is working fine with the validation but for some reason custom messages are not appearing when typing fx wrong email.

```
************Jquery***************   
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#addCustomerForm').validate({
    rules: {
    firstName: {
    required: true

    },
            lastName: {
            required: true

            },
            email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true

            },
            phone: {
            required: true,
                    digits: true,
                    minlength: 8
            },
            city: {
            required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 30
            },
            street: {
            required: true,
                    minlegnth: 2,
                    maxlength: 15
            },
            zipcode: {
            required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    maxlength: 4

            },
            country: {
            required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 10
            },
            password: {
            required: true,
                    password: true,
                    minlength: 3,
                    maxlength: 15 

            },
            messages: {
            email: {
            required: "We need customers email address to contact",
                    email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
            },
            city : {
            required : " City must be  filled in",
                    minlength : "At least 3 characters long",
                    maxlength : "Should not exceed 30 characters"
            }
            }


    }
    });
            $(window).load(function() {
    $('.log-out').fadeIn(200);
    });
    });
```

Comment: You don't need to include `jquery.validate.js` *and* `jquery.validate.min.js` -- they're functionally identical. Same goes for the other duplicate scripts. You're including jQuery twice, as well, which is almost certainly causing problems.

Comment: And for some reason you're including two different versions of jQuery and two different versions of the validation script.

Comment: I changed that, thanks. but it didn't change anything. messages still does not appear

Comment: <p><label id="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email"  id="emailInput"> <br/></p>
All my form fields look like this

Comment: can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Your braces are out of place. You have `messages` as a property of the `rules` object. It should be at the same level as `rules`.

You have this:

```
$('#addCustomerForm').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: { ... },
        ...
        messages: { ... }
    }
});
```

When you should have this:

```
$('#addCustomerForm').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: { ... },
        ...
    },
    messages: { ... }
});
```